# how to find shared dimensions in two or more cubes in Mondrian

Tags: olap, olap-cube, mondrian, rolap, olap4j

i have many cubes A B C ,...

and i want to find all the common dimensions between these cubes by Mondrian

notice shared dimensions in each cube could have different names so using of

```
cube.getDimensions().getUniqeName()
Or 
cube.getDimensions().getName()
```

doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to use the olap4j API. Start by getting an olap4j connection from your Mondrian instance. After that, the Schema metadata object can give you what you need if you call:

```
org.olap4j.Schema.getSharedDimensions()
```

More details on the API are [available here](http://olap4j.org/api/).

Comment: but it gives me all of the shared dimensions ... i need shared dimensions between two cubed and because of different name used in each cube these sharedDimensions don't help